# Choosing a random number

Tags: java, arrays, random

How can I randomly choose a number from a list of given numbers in Java?

I have only these 5 numbers: 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000

Now I have to select any one number from this set of numbers randomly.

My code to try this

```
int ar[] = new int[4];
ar[0] = 1000;
ar[1] = 2000;
ar[2] = 3000;
ar[4] = 4000;

int randomArrayIndex = num.nextInt(ar.length);
```

Comment: What is `num`? And what is the result of your code (which is not complete I guess)? Please post a complete code that you have tried.

Comment: Given that `num` is an instance of the `Random` class, you're doing it quite right. What is _not_ working for you with this code?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas.. May be for you, and not for OP.

Comment: I'm assuming `ar[4]=4000;` should read `ar[3]=4000`, as index `4` does not exist (the _4th_ index does, but that is index **3**, because they start from 0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int randomArrayIndex = new Random().nextInt(ar.length); 
int number = ar[randomArrayIndex];
```

Comment: It can generate same number more than once.

Comment: @AchintyaJha, so what? There is not requirement like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static int myRandom(int low, int high) {
    return (int) (Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
}
```

and set low and high to 0 and 4.

Comment: +1 or you can have a low of 1 and a high of 5 and multiple by 1000

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat numbers from original array:

```
 Integer [] array = {1000,2000,3000,4000};
 Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
```

If only one random number is required from the given array .

```
int[] array = {1000,2000,3000,4000};

int randomNumber = array[(int)(Math.random()*array.length)];
```

Comment: @Destrictor Its not a good approach ?

Comment: It seems a bit wasteful if you only want the one number :). If he needs all of them in a random order though, this is a very nice solution.

Comment: @Destrictor Yes, I wrote the conditions for both case. Thanks.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Can you explain why Math.random() not recommended ?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I used and it works....

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov What difference does it make on this array? No difference at all.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Yes, so what? We cant edit ? I got comment on my previous answer and I edited.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov You downvoted me without any reason. And why should I copy and paste your answer. Google works on my computer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23831/discussion-between-achintya-jha-and-nikolay-kuznetsov)

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Sir you think you are good. But I selected and accepted that answer due to the fulfillment of my query. And I just want a solution and not a lecture. Got it

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov

     int[] array = {1000,2000,3000,4000};

     int randomNumber = array[(int)(Math.random()*array.length)];